# Initialising UIViewController subclass error

Tags: swift2

I am learning Swift and I have a compile error:

```
class ListScansVC: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  internal var scans: [Scan]
  internal var dataSource: ListScanDataSource

  init(scans: [Scan]){
    self.scans = scans
    dataSource = ListScanDataSource.init(scans: scans)
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dataSource.registerReusableViewsForTableView(tableView)
  }
}
```

In another ViewController i am doing:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scan = Scan(title : "Ticket", scanDate: NSDate())
    let listScanVC = ListScansVC.init(scans: [scan])

    self.displayChildContent(ListScansVC)
}

func displayChildContent(content : UIViewController){
    self.addChildViewController(content)
    self.view.addSubview(content.view)
    content.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

The error is:
"Cannot convert value of Type 'ListScansVC.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `init` method in Swift like

```
init(scans :[Scan]){)
```

has be be called with

```
let listScanVC = ListScansVC(scans: [scan])
```

in the next line you have to pass the instance (starting with a lowercase letter) rather than the type

```
self.displayChildContent(listScanVC)
```

I'd recommended to use more distinctive names to avoid that type/instance confusion.

Comment: arg stupid error!!!. the Swift autocompletion is still horrible. Thanks for your answer.